# Mac WebView - remember login information

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication, webview

I have a WebView (macOS). When user opens Facebook and login, I want to store these information and use them next time. (currently my WebView does not "remember" anything)

In previous WebKit implementation, these saved data was taken from Safari, now this is gone.

Any idea how to do it, what principles use? I'd like to avoid Keychain and storing passwords in general, it'll be great if I could inhereit this data from Safari or so... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by missing WebFrameLoadDelegate.